# django-tables2 - accessing values of other columns in a table class

Tags: django, django-tables2

Let's assume I have the following table class:

```
class TestTable(tables.Table):
    id = tables.Column()
    description = tables.Column()

    def render_description(self, value):
        return mark_safe('''<a href=%s>%s</a>''' % (???, value))
```

Is it possible to access the value of the column "id" in the render method, so that I can build up a link which leads to the id but shows the text which depends on the 'description'-field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a quick glance at the docs for [render_FOO](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods) it looks like you can just do:

```
class TestTable(tables.Table):
    id = tables.Column()
    description = tables.Column()

    def render_description(self, value, record):
        return mark_safe('''<a href=%s>%s</a>''' % (record.id, value)
```

Not sure of the exact shape of a row record, so it might be `record['id']`, the link to the docs should help with exploration...

Comment: Great! I didn't know that there is a special object which stores the whole record and can be accessed by passing it as a parameter. By the way, your second guess was right, it's a dictionary so that it must be accessed by record['id']. Many thanks!

Comment: `record` is what ever type your objects in your data are. If you're using an array of `dict`, then `record` will be a `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

@Darb Thank you, that option works perfectly. However I was wondering if there is any way to do this using accesors instead of hacking a text column to output html...

In my case I use

```
# tables.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
#...

class FieldTable(tables.Table):
allows__count = tables.LinkColumn(viewname=None, attrs={'td': {'class': 'leftA'}},
                                  verbose_name='No. of Allowed values')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FieldTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_allows__count(self, value, record):
    if value!=0:
        a = reverse(viewname='dict:field_detail',
                       kwargs=
                       {'field_slug': record.slug,
                        'extract_slug': record.extract.slug,
                        'system_slug': record.extract.system.slug})
        return mark_safe('<a href={}>{}</a>'.format(a, value))
```

However I would like to replace the mark_safe, for something that calls the accessor of allows__count and returns the reverse hyperlink and the value...

Anyway works for know